# User logged changes when other one loggs in (from another computer)

Tags: java, tomcat, servlet-filters

I really need any help with this.
I have a JSF application with PrimeFaces running on tomcat 6.

I thought I had completed the application, but when testing it, i found a huge problem.
When I login into the application with an user (ex. 'admin') in computer 1, and then login with another user (ex. 'peter') on computer 2, the computer1 now cannot access the pages allowed to the user admin. And if I later loggin again in computer 1 with admin user, now in computer 2 peter has access to all the pages allowed to admin.

It's like I have one session for all the tomcat sessions or something like that.

I searched throw my application and found nothing with @applicationScoped, I have all @sessionScoped beans.

I don't know what to do. Please help.

I attach here my customized filter:

```
public abstract class AbstractLoginFilter implements javax.servlet.Filter {

protected ServletContext servletContext;

@Override
public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) {
    servletContext = filterConfig.getServletContext();
}

@Override
public void doFilter(
        ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
        throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
    HttpServletResponse resp = (HttpServletResponse) response;
    String pageReq = req.getRequestURL().toString();        
    HttpSession session = req.getSession(false);

    String[] temp = pageReq.split("/faces", 2);

    String url = temp[1];
    resp.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    req.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

    if ("/login.xhtml".equals(url)) { 

        continueExecution(chain, request, response);
    } else {

        if (session == null) {

            //session timeout check.
            if (req.getRequestedSessionId() != null && !req.isRequestedSessionIdValid()) {

                System.out.println("La sesión ha expirado");
                session = req.getSession(true);

                //si es un ajax
                if ("partial/ajax".equals(req.getHeader("Faces-Request"))) {
                    resp.setContentType("text/xml");
                    resp.getWriter().append("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>").printf("<partial-response><redirect url=\"%s\"></redirect></partial-response>", "/Autorack/faces/login.xhtml");
                } else {
                    resp.sendRedirect("/Autorack/faces/login.xhtml");
                }
            }
        } else {
            if (Global.getLoggedUser() == null) {
                resp.sendRedirect("/Autorack/faces/login.xhtml");
            } else {
                if (isPublicPage(url) || isAuth(url)) {
                    continueExecution(chain, request, response);
                } else {

                    resp.sendRedirect("/Autorack/faces/noAutorizacion.xhtml");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

private void continueExecution(FilterChain chain, ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
    HttpServletResponse resp = (HttpServletResponse) response;

    //when i make a BACK
    if (!req.getRequestURI().startsWith(req.getContextPath() + ResourceHandler.RESOURCE_IDENTIFIER)) { // Skip JSF resources (CSS/JS/Images/etc)
        resp.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"); // HTTP 1.1.
        resp.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache"); // HTTP 1.0.
        resp.setDateHeader("Expires", 0); // Proxies.
    }
    chain.doFilter(request, response);
}

private boolean isPublicPage(String url) {
    List<String> urlsPublicas = new ArrayList<String>();
    urlsPublicas.add("/inicio.xhtml");
    urlsPublicas.add("/noAutorizacion.xhtml");
    urlsPublicas.add("/usuario/CambioPassword.xhtml");

    return urlsPublicas.contains(url);


}

@Override
public void destroy() {
}

/**
 * logic to accept or reject access to the page, check log in status
 * @return true when authentication is deemed valid
 */
protected abstract boolean isAuth(String reqPage);
}
```

And here is my web.xml

```xml
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
<filter>
    <description>Customizable Filter</description>
    <filter-name>customFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.oriuken.autorack.security.LoginFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>customFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>                
</filter-mapping>
<error-page>
    <error-code>401</error-code>
    <location>/noAutorizacion.xhtml?faces-redirect=true</location>
</error-page>
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
    <param-value>Production</param-value>
</context-param>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
</session-config>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>faces/index.xhtml</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
<context-param>
    <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>
    <param-value>casablanca</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>primefaces.PUSH_SERVER_URL</param-name>
    <param-value>ws://localhost:8088</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
<param-name>javax.faces.DATETIMECONVERTER_DEFAULT_TIMEZONE_IS_SYSTEM_TIMEZONE</param-name>
<param-value>true</param-value>
```

Thanks for any clue !

Comment: The `Global.getLoggedUser()` looks as being a `static` method very scary in this context. I think this is the whole culprit, that you're storing the logged-in user as a `static` variable.

Comment: I just notice that, you are amazing BalusC, as always... but what should i do ?  the Global class has a static Hashmap where I put -among other things- the user that loggs in, so I can access him anywhere on the application. How can I replace that ? ... and thanks for your time again.

Comment: I'm going to get the user from a session bean, i think is the correct way, But, I have other things in that static hashmap that I get from the database and are equals to everyone in the app, like generic values (taxes, general messages, etc.). That values, may I leave it in that static hashmap or should I move they to an application scoped bean ?

Comment: I managed to solve it using a session bean, thanks a lot BalusC... can you tell me what can I do with those others general values I use in the static hashmap ?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using

```
Global.getLoggedUser()
```

Get some hand on `ThreadLocal` which we have implemented to achieve the same.

Here is some code snippet which might help you...

```
public class UserHolder {

private static ThreadLocal<User> userThreadLocal = new ThreadLocal<User>();

private static Log log = LogFactory.getLog(UserHolder.class);

public UserHolder(User user) {
    if (userThreadLocal.get() == null) {
        userThreadLocal.set(user);
        log.debug("User bound to thread " + user.getUsername()); 
    } else {
        log.debug("User already bound to thread " + user.getUsername());
    }
}

public static User getUser() {
    return userThreadLocal.get();
}

public static void setUser(User user) {
        userThreadLocal.set(user);
}

public static void remove() {
    userThreadLocal.remove();
}
}
```

In the application filter post authentication we set up the User in `UserHolder` by reading it from session variable like:

```
 new UserHolder((User) session.getAttribute("USER_ATTR_KEY"));
 // deliver request to next filter
 chain.doFilter(request, response);
```

Comment: thanks for your time, but I managed to solve it using a session scoped bean. Thanks again !